# How to change decimal column's format of Kendo Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, format

I want my Kendo Grid decimal column to value like 12,52,36,536.00. How can I format the column?

Answer (score -1):

First you need set proper culture for that format (in your case is similar to `en-US`):

```
kendo.culture("en-US");
```

Then set format `{0:n2}` to the grid column (`n2` means 2 decimal places):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    ...
    format: "{0:n2}"
  } ... ],
  ...
});
```